# C# console app export crystal report error

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports, export

The following code running fine on my PC, but when I publish the app to the server and install it. It gives me error. 
This is a console app, targeting .net framework 4,
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
crystal report support pack 13. 
I have installed runtime engine on the server x64

```
string pdf = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\zzz.pdf";

                string rpt = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\zzz.rpt";
                ReportDocument cryRpt;
                cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                cryRpt.Load(rpt);
                cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("******", "*******");

                //cryRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, pdf");

                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                Stream exportStream = cryRpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                exportStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                byte[] content = memoryStream.ToArray();

                // Write out PDF from memory stream. 
                Console.WriteLine(pdf);
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(pdf))
                {
                    fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
                }
```

This is the error 
When I using "ExportToStream" it gives me error as the following. 
When I export it to disk it gives me the similar error instead of using ExportToSteam. What I don;t get is When I am exporting it as stream, I am pointing to any location , why does it throw me "The system can not find the path specified" 
[image: asdsad]